# Can't find formula for multiple rows&column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to find a way to have this data:

[image: Data]

I want a formula to find if the number is 5 I get the following result in 2 columns:

[image: Result]

First column is the long number and the second column is the header of each column. I have tested with QUERY function, but I'm not an expert and I only have managed to find the second column.

=QUERY(A1:I4,"SELECT A WHERE B=5",0)
But I want the B column to by dynamic based on the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: the formula is tested on Excel 365. `A1:I4` is defined as a table named `tab_data`.

**B9 Formula**

```
=TRANSPOSE(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(" ", TRUE, IF(tab_data[[DC]:[NB]]=$B$7, tab_data[title below], ""))," "))
```

**C9 Formula**

```
=TRANSPOSE(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(" ", TRUE, IF(tab_data[[DC]:[NB]]=$B$7, tab_data[[#Headers],[DC]:[NB]], ""))," "))
```

Formulas w/o table reference

```
B9 Formula  =TRANSPOSE(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(" ", TRUE, IF(B2:I4=$B$7, A2:A4, ""))," "))
C9 Formula  =TRANSPOSE(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(" ", TRUE, IF(B2:I4=$B$7, B1:I1, ""))," "))
```

---

Combine two formulas with `HSTACK`

```
=HSTACK(TRANSPOSE(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(" ", TRUE, IF(tab_data[[DC]:[NB]]=$B$7, tab_data[title below], ""))," ")),
    TRANSPOSE(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(" ", TRUE, IF(tab_data[[DC]:[NB]]=$B$7, tab_data[[#Headers],[DC]:[NB]], ""))," ")))
```

OR

```
=LET(s,tab_data[[DC]:[NB]]=$B$7,
    x,TRANSPOSE(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(" ", TRUE, IF(s, tab_data[title below], ""))," ")),
    y,TRANSPOSE(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(" ", TRUE, IF(s, tab_data[[#Headers],[DC]:[NB]], ""))," ")),
    HSTACK(x,y))
```

Credit to `P.b`, simplify formula with `TOCOL`.

```
=LET(s,tab_data[[DC]:[NB]]=$B$7,
x,TOCOL(IF(s, tab_data[title below], 1/0),3),
y,TOCOL(IF(s, tab_data[[#Headers],[DC]:[NB]], 1/0),3),
HSTACK(x,y))
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. It says "Error: Formula parse error." when I paste it with the same layout as you.

Comment: Insert a table named `tab_data` or replace it with cell range reference in formula. I have updated it with two approaches.

Comment: Oh, yeah I forgot to insert a table like your screenshot good point. It should work now. I just need to get the french formulas and replace "," with ";". Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I just realized, if you prefer condensing into a single formula, you can use `hstack` to combine the formulas from both columns.

Comment: I just made it work and it works perfectly, I needed to hardcode the 5 for "5" as a text. I will try to hstack now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I can't find the french formula for hstack, but it's fine with 2 functions. As long as it works :D

Comment: Found it "ASSEMB.H". Works perfectly as 1 formula. Thank you again

Comment: My answer looks very lengthy but tried it in my way.. @p.b sir's answer looks very good.

Answer (score 2):

In Office 365 you could make use of `REPT` to repeat the values if the condition is met:

```
=LET(condition,1/(B2:I4=5),
     v,REPT(A2:A4,condition),
     h,REPT(B1:I1,condition),
HSTACK(TOCOL(v,2),TOCOL(h,2)))
```

First the `condition` is declared, If a cell's value in Range `B2:I4` equals `5` it returns `1/TRUE`. Where TRUE is converted to the numerical representation of TRUE: `1`, so `1/1 = 1`.
If the condition is not met it returns `1/FALSE` or `1/0 = #DIV/0! error`.

If we use the array of ones and errors inside REPT and use the vertical (`v`) header cells it creates an array of the header value where the condition is `1` and an error value at the error.
Same goes for the horizontal headers (`h`).

If we use `TOCOL` on the arrays it flattens all data to one column. and the second argument of `TOCOL` `2` is to ignore error values. We do that array by array and than stack them using HSTACK:

*`A6#` and `A10#` in the picture below are to demonstrate the REPT-array with it's errors.*

[image]

Comment: `=LET(condition;1/(B2:I4=5);
     v;REPT(A2:A4;condition);
     h;REPT(B1:I1;condition);
ASSEMB.H(TOCOL(v;2);TOCOL(h;2)))` for your version of Excel, if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

My Answer ..

[image: Result]

```
=LET(ip,A3:A5,op,B3:I5,dd,B7,rslt,B2:I2,cn,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(ip)),
HSTACK(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",",,REPT(ip&",",TOCOL(INDEX(MMULT(--(op=dd),TRANSPOSE(--(op=dd))),cn,cn)))),,",",TRUE),
TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",",,IF(op=dd,rslt,"")),,",",TRUE)))
```